# Are there limits to the `keys` parameter when querying a Cloudant view?

Tags: database, couchdb, cloudant

Are there any size limits to the `keys` parameter that can be passed when querying a Cloudant view? Or perhaps this is limited by request size?

Also, in cases where a view query may return a large set of data, are there limits to how much can be returned in a single response?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a hard Cloudant limit as to how many keys you can pass but there is a limit to how much data you can supply as a GET parameter to an HTTP endpoint e.g. `?keys=["a","b","c"]` - the limit is 2KB per request. There is more detail on that in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request#2659995)

You can make a [POST equivalent request](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant#postview), passing `keys` in the body of the request. In that case you'd be limited by the maximum request body of 10MB. However, I would try to keep such requests below 2000 key items.